# Placing texts between pictures

Tags: html, css

How do i make a scroll-able horizontal line up of round shaped images that originate from a square shaped images with a captions below. And if possible make it seperate each other. Sorry for the bad grammar

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the question is how to structure the elements in HTML before we come to the CSS part. Since you're asking for a line up of multiple elements having a "container - element" structure seems suggestive.

```
div (container)

    div (element1)
    div (element2)
    div (element3)
    ...

/div
```

Now we have to put the round image together with the caption below in the element. That's also pretty simple:

```
div (element)

    img (circular picture)
    div (caption)

/div
```

Let's translate this into proper HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="elem">
        <img src=""/>
        <div>Caption #1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="elem">
        <img src=""/>
        <div>Caption #2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="elem">
        <img src=""/>
        <div>Caption #3</div>
    </div>

    ...

</div>
```

Time to get into CSS. As of right now every element is aligned vertically, not horizontally. One solution I personally really like is Flexbox. It lets you play dynamically with multiple elements which is exactly what we are looking for.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

That's enough to have each Element aligned horizontally as Flexbox structures the items horizontally by default. `overflow-x: scroll;` prevents the items to resize the web page and will make the container horizontally scrollable as a fix.

The only thing that's left is to make the image circular and that is super easy to do. All we have to do is to add a `border-radius` which is bigger than the image size itself:

```
.elem img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 500px;
}
```

Done.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.elem {
  padding: 8px;
}

.elem img {
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: grey;
  
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5000px;
}

.elem div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem">
    <img class="pic" src="https://www.famousbirthdays.com/headshots/justin-bieber-2.jpg" />
    <div>Caption #1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elem">
    <img/>
    <div>Caption #2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elem">
    <img/>
    <div>Caption #3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elem">
    <img/>
    <div>Caption #4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elem">
    <img/>
    <div>Caption #5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elem">
    <img/>
    <div>Caption #6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elem">
    <img/>
    <div>Caption #7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```